# Cordova communication error between my app and backend service

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cordova

My javascript and php in my cordova application seem not to be communicating. my backend PHP service not recieving value assigned to variable in ajax. The value is being assigned before it is sent. Ensured that by getting an alert.

My Ajax query:

```
    type:'GET',
    data:{user_id:user},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    url: 'http://******.com/*********.php',
```

My PHP:

```
    <?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    include ('connection.php');
    $user_id = $_GET["user_id"];
```

The variable `$user_id` returns a null value even though the value is assigned to the variable before its sent.